# how to create a auto update code for wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom plugin in wordpress. Now I was wondering on how can I update the codes of the installed plugin when the there is something that I have changed the code from my local?

what I have looking for is an automatic update button that will update the entire code of the installed plugin.

I am new with this and I have searched in the internet but I have found nothing and others won't work.

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you have this linked in the WordPress Plugin Repo, it does this with most of the latest versions of WordPress automatically. This link may help a bit https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common ways to do it, with most of the latest versions of WordPress is to apply for your plugin to be hosted with WordPress officially. This can be done [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add/).

Once you have done that and it gets approved, install the plugin from the repository. It should then register within a few minutes if an update has been processed through the system -- notifying all users of updated code.

Full info is located at http://wordpress.org/plugins/add/

Comment: is it also possible if a private plugin? I mean will be hosted on private server